# Not jaundiced but bright

Tags: riddle

In life I am yellow,
Not jaundiced, but bright.
In death I am hollow
But, broken, I bite!

What am I?

Comment: What a pleasing riddle!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> a lightbulb

In life I am yellow,

Not jaundiced, but bright.

> Incandescent lightbulbs give off a yellowish light

In death I am hollow

But, broken, I bite!

> When lightbulbs die, they are hollow(no longer full of light), and when broken, the glass can hurt you